# Stata dummy variables start date end date

Tags: stata, dummy-variable

I want to rearrange dummy variables which are currently not in an usable format for Stata: I have a start date and an end date for different measures (&different countries)- a dummy indicates "1" when the start date of the measure and the data-date "date2" equal. However, I need the dummy variable to be "1" until the end date (so the "active" measures).
Any ideas how to solve this?

```
clear all
    sort country date2
    by country: replace M1=M1[_n-1] if date_end2<=date2 & date_end2>0
```

My current code can't solve it, I don't know how to adress the end date right: (example for one Measure)
It is quite complicated, as the same type of measures can also overlap.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input float date2 str3 country float(date_start2 date_end2 M1 M2 M3 M4 M5)
21914 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21915 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21916 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21917 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21918 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21919 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21920 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21921 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21922 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21923 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21924 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21925 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21926 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21927 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21928 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21929 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21930 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21931 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21932 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21933 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21934 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21935 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21936 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21937 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21938 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21939 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21940 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21941 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21942 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21943 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21944 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21945 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21946 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21947 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21948 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21949 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21950 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21951 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21952 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21953 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21954 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21955 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21956 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21957 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21958 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21959 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21960 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21961 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21962 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21963 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21964 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21965 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21966 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21967 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21968 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21969 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21970 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21971 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21972 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21973 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21974 "FRA" 21974 22175 . . . 1 .
21975 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21976 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21977 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21978 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21979 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21980 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21981 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21982 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21983 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21984 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21985 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21986 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21987 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21988 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21989 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21990 "FRA" 21990 22045 1 . . . 1
21991 "FRA" 21991 22046 . 1 . . 1
21992 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21993 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21994 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21995 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21996 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21997 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21998 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
21999 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
22000 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
22001 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
22002 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
22003 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
22004 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
22005 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
22006 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
22007 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
22008 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
22009 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
22010 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
22011 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
22012 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
22013 "FRA"     .     . . . . . .
end
format %tdCCYY-NN-DD date2
format %tdCCYY-NN-DD date_start2
format %tdCCYY-NN-DD date_end2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you copy downwards like this

```
bysort country (date) : replace date_start2 = date_start2[_n-1] if missing(date_start2)
```

with similar code for `date_end2`, theh you can calculate new variables based on a comparison of date variables within observations. See [this FAQ](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/replacing-missing-values/) for more explanation and also `help inrange()`.